# Ошибка при отправке почты Outlook

Tags: golang

Есть код для отправки электронного письма

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    "gopkg.in/gomail.v2"
)

func main() {
    m := gomail.NewMessage()

    m.SetHeader("From", "mymail@outlook.com")      /* Меняю на нужное перед запуском кода */
    m.SetHeader("To", "recipient@mail.com") /* Меняю на нужное перед запуском кода */
    m.SetHeader("Subject", "Test")
    m.SetBody("text/plain", "Hello")

    conn := gomail.NewDialer("smtp-mail.outlook.com", 587, "mymail@outlook.com", "passwordFromMyMail")

    log.Println(conn.DialAndSend(m))
}
```

Но при запуске выдает ошибку

`gomail: could not send email 1: 554 5.2.252 SendAsDenied; mymail@outlook.com not allowed to send as mymail@outlook.com; STOREDRV.Submission.Exception:SendAsDeniedException.MapiExceptionSendAsDenied; Failed to process message due to a permanent exception with message Cannot submit message`

При гуглении не нахожу, в чем у меня прокол) Кто-нибудь в курсе, как добиться отправки письма при таком коде?

Answer (score 0):

Зашел на сайт outlook. попытался войти в почту и там нужно было сперва проверить и прнять данные мои. После этого заработало все.